# Get Data from qcombo box in stringlist data

Tags: qt, qcombobox

Im using Qt creator 3.5.1 and creating a simple gui.

Im wondering how to get data from combobox that is in qstringlist here's my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"





MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
     list=(QStringList()<<"Japan"<<"Korea"<<"Philippines"<<"Us");
     ui->comboBox->addItems(list);
     ui->comboBox_2->addItems(list);
     str1 = ui->comboBox->currentText();
     str2 = ui->comboBox_2->currentText();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    integer_value = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
    if(str1 == "Us" && str2 == "Philippines")
    {
        answer = integer_value * 47.73;
        result = result.number(answer);
        ui->label->setText(result);

    }
}
```

when im using this code it works:

without using QStringList:

```
ui->comboBox->addItem("Us");
ui->comboBox_2->addItem("Philippines");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize str1 and str2 once (with "Japan"), and they never changed (according to your code). If you want to get current comboBox text when you press button, you need to check it in `on_pushButton_clicked()` slot. Something like that:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    str1 = ui->comboBox->currentText();
    str2 = ui->comboBox_2->currentText();
    if(str1 == "Us" && str2 == "Philippines")
        {
            answer = integer_value * 47.73;
            result = result.number(answer);
            ui->label->setText(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh,Thank you very much,it works like a charm. What do you mean by i initialize it by once with "Japan" and never changed,is it different initializing in constructor than in a private slot function? why does it initialize once in constructor which is "japan" ?

Comment: I mean that after `ui->comboBox->addItems(list);` `comboBox` has 4 elements and it's current element is "Japan". Then you assign this value to str1. So when you check it in the slot it still has value "Japan", while current value of comboBox can be different.